# I'm working on Kali Linux and I can't access downloaded script file facebook.py

Tags: kali-linux

After I typed `apt-get install python-mechanize` in the Kali Linux terminal, when I try to install `facebook.py` script by typing `python facebook.py` located on `/root/Desktop/facebook.py` I get this message

```
:python: can't open file 'facebook.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Comment: Some context would be nice. What are you trying to do? As in, what is `facebook.py`, where are you supposed to get it from, and what do you want to do with it? Also, what does `python-mechanize` have to do with it?

Comment: I want to use the script but I can't install it

Comment: See questions above.

Comment: I'm following a step by step tuttorial

Comment: You need to be in the directory where `facebook.py` is in order to run it without specifying the full path.

I'll also add: you should find a basic Linux/Unix tutorial to help orient yourself.

Comment: Can you tell me the command in order to run it,pdo?

Comment: *If* the file you want to run is `/root/Desktop/facebook.py`, then you want to run: `python /root/Desktop/facebook.py`


...and now you really need to do some reading on your own :)

Comment: If you are using a step by step tutorial, it might be helpful if you were to provide a link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
    ls -alh
```

Make sure the file is in the same directory that you are running python in.

Comment: sorry for asking but how should I use that command?

Comment: You should see a listing of the files in the current directory you are in.  If facebook.py isn't in there then you are in the wrong directory.